# Remove special characters from a string

Tags: vb.net, string, newline

These are valid characters:

```
a-z
A-Z
0-9
-
/
```

How do I remove all other characters from my string?

Comment: Which characters aren't special? Do you want the cleaned string to only contain `-` and `/` or do you want to keep other characters too?

Comment: a-zA-Z0-9 and -,/ rest all not needed but mainly right now i need to remove crlf,cr,lf using vb.net

Answer (score 27):

```
Dim cleanString As String = Regex.Replace(yourString, "[^A-Za-z0-9\-/]", "")
```

Comment: Little support requesting.. If I need to exclude a special character from this. Not special character, say If I want white space and # symbol not to be replaced.. how can I modify this..

Comment: @sforsandeep: Just add them into the group, for example: `[^A-Za-z0-9\-/#\s]` or similar.

Answer (score 6):

Use either regex or Char class functions like IsControl(), IsDigit() etc. Get a list of these functions here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char_members.aspx

Here's a sample regex example:

(Import this before using RegEx)

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
```

In your function, write this

```
Regex.Replace(strIn, "[^\w\\-]", "")
```

This statement will replace any character that is not a word, \ or -. For e.g. aa-b@c will become aa-bc.

Comment: +1 The OP probably wants to keep spaces as well - though maybe not tabs (?) which would be `Regex.Replace(strIn, "[^\w\\- ]", "")`

Comment: Watch out! The `\w` class doesn't only match alphanumerics. For example, your regex won't correctly clean *"a_string_containing_underscores"*. (Also, the OP wants to allow forward-slashes, not backslashes.)

Comment: Hmm. Slash should be different.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim txt As String
txt = Regex.Replace(txt, "[^a-zA-Z 0-9-/-]", "")
```

Comment: An explanation of the regex would be helpful as part of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Function RemoveCharacter(ByVal stringToCleanUp)
    Dim characterToRemove As String = ""
        characterToRemove = Chr(34) + "#$%&'()*+,-./\~"
        Dim firstThree As Char() = characterToRemove.Take(16).ToArray()
        For index = 1 To firstThree.Length - 1
            stringToCleanUp = stringToCleanUp.ToString.Replace(firstThree(index), "")
        Next
        Return stringToCleanUp
End Function
```

Comment: String.Replace("char", "")?

Answer (score 0):

I've used the first solution from LukeH, but then realized that this code replaces the dot for extension, therefore I've just upgraded the code slightly:

```
 Dim fileNameNoExtension As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileNameWithExtension)
 Dim cleanFileName As String = Regex.Replace(fileNameNoExtension, "[^A-Za-z0-9\-/]", "") & Path.GetExtension(fileNameWithExtension)
```

`cleanFileName`  will the file name with no special characters with extension.