# Read a text file and display result in a window

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a text file which contains about 60 lines. I would like to parse out all the text from that file and display in a window. The text file contains words that are separated by an underscore. I would like to use regular expression to solve this problem.

**Update:**

This is my code as of now. I am trying to read "filename" in my code.

```
Dim filename = "D:\databases.txt"
Dim regexpression As String = "/^[^_]*_([^_]*)\w/"
```

I know I don't have much done here anyway but I am trying to learn VB on my own and have gotten stuck here.

Please feel free to suggest what I should be doing instead.

Comment: **How** would you like to solve the problem with underscores? Replace with spaces?

Comment: Text between underscores should be shown without underscores after the button click. I would like reiterate that onButtonClick, code should go to the specified path "D:\xyz.txt", read all the data and resulting output should be without any special characters.

Comment: It would be a good idea if you paste what you have already done. That way we can help you out instead of doing the work for you.

Comment: Regarding your update, you can use the regex, but I would do it the old school way - easier to maintain and you have more control this way (see my answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
TextBox1.Lines = IO.File.ReadAllLines("fileName")
```

To remove underscores:

```
TextBox1.Lines = IO.File.ReadAllLines("fileName").Replace("_", String.Empty)
```

If you also need other special characters removed, you can use `Regex.Replace`:

- [Remove special characters from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701018/how-remove-all-special-charactersexcept-and-from-a-string-including-all-cr)

Also on MSDN:

- [How to: Strip Invalid Characters from a String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/844skk0h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Or the old school way - loop through all characters, and filter only those you need:

- [Most efficient way to remove special characters from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120198/most-efficient-way-to-remove-special-characters-from-string)