# How to trim spaces

Tags: excel, string, vb.net

I have text in Excel like this:

```
            120
124569       abasd          12345
```

There are sapces both to the left and to the right side.

I copy this from Excel and paste as text. When I check this, it shows like this when I click on button.

Code:

```
abArray= abArray & "," & gridview1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Text

For k = 3 To 17
    bArray= abArray& "," & Val(gridview1.Rows(i).Cells(k).Text)
Next
```

In `abArray` this shows as:

```
0, abasd      ,12345,0,0,0,0,0
```

I want to remove/trim spaces both from left and right.

I have tried `abArray.Trim()` but this still show spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove **all** the spaces out of the end result consider [String.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Returns a new string in which all occurrences of a specified Unicode character or String in the current string are replaced with another specified Unicode character or String.

Example use:

```
Dim s As String = "0, abasd      ,12345,0,0,0,0,0"
s = s.Replace(" ", "")
```

This would output:

```
0,abasd,12345,0,0,0,0,0
```

It may also be worth using a [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) to join all your values together as this is good practice when looping as you are. At this point you could use [String.Trim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3(v=vs.110).aspx). This would preserve any spaces that are within your value. In order words it would only remove the spaces from the beginning and the end of the value.

Example use:

```
Dim sb As New StringBuilder
For k = 0 To 17
    sb.Append(String.Format("{0},", gridview1.Rows(i).Cells(k).Text.Trim()))
Next

Dim endResult As String = sb.ToString().TrimEnd(","c)
```

`endResult` would output:

```
0,abasd,12345,0,0,0,0,0
```

> You will have to import `System.Text` in order to make use of the `StringBuilder` class.

Answer (score 0):

Use the VB.NET Trim function to remove leading and trailing spaces, change this one line of code:

```
abArray= abArray& "," & Val(Trim(gridview1.Rows(i).Cells(k).Text))
```

`abArray.Trim()` does not work because you did not give the Trim function anything to trim.

Comment: this shows error .. System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.  ...

Comment: That's probably because your loop either begins or ends with k being a invalid index into Cells.  Put a breakpoint on the line of code `abArray= abArray& "," & Val(gridview1.Rows(i).Cells(k).Text.Trim)` and see how many cells there are and what the value of k is.

Comment: ok what if we remove characters like i have number like this .. 101730921&#160;  so there is special characters so  i remove these?

Comment: I would use RegEX, there is a good example of that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701018/remove-special-characters-from-a-string

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
    abArray = abArray & "," & gridview1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Text.Trim

    For k = 3 To 17
        abArray= abArray& "," & Val(gridview1.Rows(i).Cells(k).Text.Trim)
    Next
```